# Modifying an existing task to add a new dependency

Tags: ant

Is it possible to modify a task and add a prerequisite to it? For instance, I have an external `build.xml` that I'm importing. It includes a debug task. I want to add the dependency `-prebuild-copy` to that task.

I would just create a wrapper task but the debug target gets called for any libraries that my project includes and I need to ensure that `-prebuild-copy` is run for all of them. I could copy and modify the other build file, but it's the one that ships with android and I don't want to have to try to update my custom version every time the SDK gets updated.

Comment: Is it a debug task or target you want to modify. From the description it's unclear.

Comment: Sorry. I'm an ant neophyte. It's a target.

Answer (score 1):

ANT has two task for importing common build logic:

- [import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html)
- [include](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html)

The following example uses the more modern [include](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/include.html).

## Example

```
|-- build-common.xml
`-- build.xml
```

Project is run as follows

```
$ ant debug
Buildfile: /home/mark/tmp/build.xml

-prebuild-copy:
     [echo] PREBUILD TARGET

common.debug:
     [echo] I AM A DEBUG TARGET

debug:
     [echo] MY DEBUG TASK
```

### build-common.xml

```
<project name="build-common">

    <target name="debug">
        <echo message="I AM A DEBUG TARGET"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="debug">

    <include file="build-common.xml" as="common"/>

    <target name="-prebuild-copy">
        <echo message="PREBUILD TARGET"/>
    </target>

    <target name="debug" depends="-prebuild-copy, common.debug">
        <echo message="MY DEBUG TASK"/>
    </target>

</project>
```